# Does pull_nested_quantifiers option work with simplify in Z3?

Tags: z3, quantifiers

I would like to pull all nested quantifiers in a formula to the outermost level. I expected the following commands to work in Z3 but they don't:

```
(set-option :pull-nested-quantifiers true)
(simplify (exists ((x Int)) (and (>= x 0) 
                            (forall ((y Int)) (and (>= y 1) (> x y))))))
```

What is the purpose of `:pull-nested-quantifiers`? How can I pull nested quantifiers using SMT-LIB or Z3 API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Z3 3.x, the `simplify` command applies only general purpose local simplification steps. "Pull-nested-quantifiers" is a pre-processing step. It will be available as a tactic/strategy in future releases. Z3 3.2 already has many built-in strategies/tactics in the SMT 2.0 front-end. The next release will have a much bigger set of tactics. They will be available also in the API. If you need this feature for some project, just send me an email and I will make a non-official (beta) release for you.

Finally, we have this preprocessing step, because the model-based quantifier instantiation MBQI module works much better if universal quantifiers do not have nested (universal) quantifiers. Your example is ok, since Z3 will eliminate the existential and replace `x` with a fresh constant.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I want to use pull-nested-quantifiers as a simplification step in order to transform formulas to Prenex Normal Form. It seems that this option is available as a preprocessing step only, right?